# is Microsoft Word 2010 free?

Tags: microsoft-word, license, product-key

I have microsoft word 2010 installed in my laptop but it seems that it is unlicensed.
[image]

But, I am still able to edit and view file with this software. But, when I tried unlicensed word 2016, I only could view file but cannot edit it. How could this happen?

Comment: There are no free versions of Microsoft Office

Comment: I got it when i bought my laptop but it still asked about product activation. What should i do?

Comment: If you don’t have a license uninstall it

Comment: @Zozzizzez The software would have been activated when you bought the laptop and whatever time period that subscription was for has now ended

Comment: It is strange, most of fucntions of Office would be disabled if you see "This product is unlicensed". Maybe you could try to run CMD as administrator, enter `cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\ospp.vbs" /dstatus` to check more activation information of Office 2010.(Please note, this command is for 64-bit Office 2010)

Comment: As mentioned, MS Office requires payment, though some PC's come with a 30-day *trial* version... after that, it requires registration. For similar functionality, try free LibreOffice or Open Office.

Answer (score 0):

There *was* a free version, with ads, of Office 2010 [Office Starter] that was paid for by computer manufacturers. I do not think it shows up as unlicensed; it would not give the message you are seeing. It was a trimmed-down version and is no longer distributed.

Microsoft has become more aggressive at enforcing its licensing requirements, thus what is happening with Word 2016 on your computer.

- Recent *Professional Plus* licenses are *volume* licenses and are not sold to individuals, except through the Home Use Program connected with employers, but they are sold by unscrupulous Internet sellers and may work for a while when installed; when Microsoft catches what is going on, the licenses stop working.

There is a free version of Microsoft Office [[Office Online](https://www.office.com/?auth=1)] that includes Word, albeit with [fewer functions](https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8?NS=WDWAENDUSER&Version=16&AppVer=WAW150&CorrelationId=6be226bc-c894-4058-97a9-4b6e3e9563a1#__toc304841573). It lets you create and edit documents; however, you must be online to use it and it works with documents stored on OneDrive, for which you can get a free account.

- There are alternatives to Microsoft Office, such as [OfficeLibre](https://www.libreoffice.org/) [free], which is open-source and works offline, which may meet your needs.

Comment: Where are you getting the info from that "_Professional Plus licenses are volume licenses_"

Comment: That is something I've known for about six years after getting burned buying one. Search the Microsoft Answers site for "professional plus." https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-professional-plus-2016/04b86d9f-afb7-44b1-bc73-bd2d9b474d76  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-professional-plus-2019/35c8b5e8-3fa2-4570-b9f2-07b87f7f6def  You can get it through Home Use Program (employer), Academic version through University, Military.

Comment: Right, you can get it through Home Use agreements, but it was also sold retail

Comment: There is no retail sale, *now*, of the Professional Plus version. My experience was with Office 2013. My memories of 2010 do not include whether or not there was a Pro Plus version available for retail. I have amended the answer to specify *recent*.

Comment: Office 2010 is [EoL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/end-of-support-for-office-2010-3a3e45de-51ac-4944-b2ba-c2e415432789) as of a month ago, coupled with it being cheaper to buy an Office 365 subscription _(same price as the equivalent Office standalone version over 4yrs)_, while also providing 1TB of OneDrive storage. Home Use programs don't use VLKs, they're normal product keys requiring normal activation _(IIRC, don't VLKs require activation through a VL server?)_, and are provided to large entities with large Microsoft contracts for employee use either free or heavily discounted